# Network Namespace (non) Isolation?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, network-namespaces

I've been doing some research on Linux and networks in general, and came across namespaces. After reading articles and learning how to set one up, I am confused.

I installed an application on my system, and when I run it in the global namespace (no namespace), I can connect to the web gui from the lan using the host's IP address. Now, when I create a namespace, and before I create any virtual adapters or do anything else, if I open the application in the namespace, I can still connect to it from the LAN using the same IP.

The command I'm using to start the service is:

```
sudo ip netns exec blue service *application* start
```

My understanding is that "network" namespaces are supposed to isolate processes. So what am I missing?

By the way, I generally use these instructions for namespaces:

[Introducing Linux Network Namespaces](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/).

Comment: What is the question?  What have you tried?  What results did you see that you didn't expect?

Comment: Why isn't the application being isolated from the network interfaces? If I open the application inside a namespace without any type of network devices, virtual or physical, I shouldn't be able to access the application's web gui from another LAN computer, because that would mean the application is communicating through my eth0 card. However, I am still able to access the application's web gui. My question is where is my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 5):

> So what am I missing?

What you're missing is that `service` communicates with `init`, essentially escaping the network namespace. The application ends up running in the same network namespace as the init system (by default).

At its core, the problem is that `service` doesn't just `fork` and `exec` the application daemon binary (which would preserve the namespace). Instead, it does little more than passing its parameters to `init` through (I believe) a Unix domain socket. Secure containers also isolate the filesystem to prevent this kind of thing.

I'd try just invoking the application daemon binary directly (under `ip netns exec [namespace]`, of course). Or use a real container software where someone else has already sorted out all the tricky details ...